Dart, completing message processing, concurrency guarantees clarification
Discussion in context of dart concurrency.
Question is asked with the mindset coming from multi-threading programming, no guarantee when concurrent state change will occur and ensuing need to manage synchronization of various possible state changes. For example:
class Outbox{

 static final _queue = Queue<Order>();


 static void _processQueueAsync() async {

  /* block1
  no await, Future in this block.

  in multithreading platform _queue can be modified (orders added/removed) 
  while this block is executing either by 
  1.1 a parallel thread; or
  1.2 suspending present thread at any point, switching to another thread and then back

  in dart _queue will not be altered while this block executes, because:
  2.1 while parallel isolate may be executing, unlike multithreading, 
      its memory is a separate instance (though possibly executing the same lexical scope) 
  2.2 current isolate keeps UNINTERRUPTED execution of the code path triggered 
      by the event loop message until the execution path completes. 
      note, "completion" includes returning Future or async/await (not the case in block1). 
      thus, unlike in multi-threading platform, dart guarantees un-interrupted 
      execution of this block. 
  end block1 */

  // block2
  await ShipAsync(order);
  /*
  From the moment above await kicks in and until it resolves (which time-wise is a subset of 
  "until the next line") _queue can be altered even in dart 
  ( including by a code outside of SendAsync() ). 
  one way to think about it, as if old message execution path completed with previous line 
  and subsequent execution is triggered by "a new message" of resolving above await/Future.
  */
  return;
 }

}

My question is about dart guarantee of no-concurrent-state-change (in memory of current isolate) in block1. Documentation is quite clear about isolates having a separate memory (2.1), which is one of two premises required. But no-interruption guarantee (2.2), I havent seen it explicitly. I think it's implicit in the way documentation describes dart concurrency, but would appreciate a confirmation.
Question: does dart guarantee uninterrupted execution of a path all the way as triggered by a message in a loop until completion of that path (save await and Future)? eg it's not like execution of a path from one message (eg UI update from screen tap) can be suspended, execution switched to a different path as triggered from another message (eg timer or stream ticked) and than switches back to previous path. that would be multithreading.
Goal: in dart no need to worry about concurrent state changes in block1 type of lexical stretches (unlike in multithreaded platforms like java/c#).

Unless a new isolate is explicitly started, everything is executed in the current isolate (usually called main). Awaiting a function does not automatically mean the function is executed in a separate isolate.

I would recommend editing this post as discussions are off-topic on stackoverflow. Rather ask one question that others can try to answer. You should be able, in principle, to accept the right answer. For discussions rather use the chat facility.

@DanR thanks Dan. I have made question more explicit, sry if it wasnt before. as for essential answer, "everything is executed in the current isolate", in this statement "everything" does leave open (unlikely) the possibility that execution isnt guaranteed to be un-interrupted between code paths as triggered by various messages in the loop and further peppered with awaits and Futures

@GiorgiSh. your understanding seems correct to me. block1 will execute uninterrupted.

One place where a Dart isolate being single-threaded is described is here: https://dart.dev/language/concurrency#isolates

The code marked as block1 in your function _processQueueAsync() is guaranteed to run synchronously.
In general, an async function runs synchronously until the first await statement is encountered.

This means that within an async function body, all synchronous code before the first await keyword executes immediately.

For more details see: Execution flow with async and await.

block1 runs sync, that was never a suspect, this would be the case be it say java or dart. Concern is concurrency.
var order = _queue.removeFirst();,
while synchronous, in multithreaded language this may not be a thread safe line. one thread may copy a member to a variable order in one instance of execution, and before that order is removed from _queue (copy+removal may not be an atomic op), another thread then may also copy the same order to another instance of order variable in concurrent execution.
question is about confirming this is not a concern in dart within block1 type code.

@GiorgiSh. each isolate is single threaded, and each isolate has its own memory, so you cannot run multiple bits of code on the same instance of _queue at the same time.

@mmcdon20 agree, as long as it is never the case: "sry current exec path, a priority msg arrived, I'll switch processing that, will come back to you later". I expect that is the case (otherwise essentially it's multi-threading), but is it ever in spec/doc? is uninterrupted ("un-switched") completion of exec path triggered by each msg in loop guaranteed?

no such thing as a priority message, it will switch to doing something else when you reach the await.
